1995 jimmy can't get c02 sensor off
Can't get c02 sensor off 1995 chevrolet jimmy. Iv tried driving it to heat it up, sprayed it with WD-40, went and bought the "special socket", and it still won't come off.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

There are much better products than wd-40, like PB Blaster or Break-Free. I'd try those, and give them more time to work.

You said you heated it through running ... that is look warm when it comes to getting something like this loose. If you're going to use heat, you need to get (at a minimum) a propane or map gas torch and get it read hot, then douse it with water or something else to get it to cool quickly. This might break the bond between the O2 sensor and the exhaust pipe.
If you don't have or can't get a torch, you might want to try using a pair of vise grips. I'm assuming the reason you are taking the O2 sensor out is to replace it. If so, it doesn't matter if you mangle the sensor.
Again, if replacing the O2 sensor, you might try cutting off the pig tail (wiring) and use a regular deep well (or impact deep well) socket on it. I wouldn't do it with anything less than a 1/2" drive. The special O2 sensor socket works great for putting them in, but when you have a stuck sensor like what you have, when you go to twist on it with the slotted socket, it tends to spread a bit and can skip over the hex at the base of the sensor ... which ... pretty much doesn't do you much good.
Even with a deep well socket you can expect to put a lot of torque on it to get it out. Do not be surprised if you either leave threads in the bung or pull the threads out of the bung in doing so. The bond between the threads can be that good. Sucks, I know, but reality.
